# threads reagarding notification

Tags: java

I was going through threads and I read that ..The notify() method is used to send a signal to one and only one of the threads that are waiting in that same object's waiting pool.
The method notifyAll() works in the same way as notify(), only it sends the signal to all of the threads waiting on the object.

Now my query is that if Lets say I have 5 threads waiting and through Notify() , i want to send to notification to thread 3 only, what logic should be there that notification is sent to thread 3 only ..!!

Comment: you could hold references to all of your `Thread` objects in a list and loop through them until you find the one you want, calling `notify()` on that Thread.

Comment: Hi Hunter , thanks a lot ,could you please show through a small code , that will be a great help..!!thanks a lot..!!

Comment: Hi Hunter, amazing logic, please if it will be a great help, if you could just please show the small demo , things will be more clearer..!! thanks a lot..!!

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly do this with `wait` and `notify`. You'd have to set a flag somewhere, have the code in the thread check it and go back to waiting if it's the wrong thread, and then call `notifyAll`.

Note that if you have to deal with this, it might be a sign that you should restructure your code. If you need to be able to notify each individual thread, you should probably make each of them wait on a different object.

Comment: Hi taymon, thanks a lot but could you please show me the small program in which say 5 threads or more are waiting and through notif() you are sending notification to thread 3 only...of your choice..that will be a great help..!!thanks a lot..!!

Comment: Hi taymon, thanks a lot but could you please show me the small program in which say 5 threads or more are waiting and through notif() you are sending notification to thread 3 only...of your choice..that will be a great help..!!thanks a lot..!! – user1320527 10 hours ago

Comment: Jiri Patera's answer provides an example of the flag approach.

Comment: Hi Taymon You also provide one implementation..in which you are storing the objects in arraylist, could you please provide that implementation again that will be a great help..!!thanks in advance..!

Comment: I have no idea how your program is structured, which really defines the entire problem for this kind of code.

Answer (score 2):

`wait-notify` is rather a low level mechanism to indicate to other threads that an event (being expected occured). Example of this is producer/consumer mechanism.

It is not a mechanism for threads to communicate to each other.
If you need something like that you are looking in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

The following code starts up five threads and sets the third one a flag which tells it that it is the only to continue. Then all of the threads that are waiting on the same lock object `lock` are notified (woken-up), but only the one selected continues. Be careful, writing multi-threaded applications is not easy at all (proper synchronization, handling the spurious wake-ups, etc.) You should not need to wake up only one particular thread from the group as this points to an incorrect problem decomposition. Anyway, here you go...

```
package test;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.start(5);
  }

  private void start(int n) {
    MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      threads[i] = new MyThread();
      /* set the threads as daemon ones, so that JVM could exit while they are still running */
      threads[i].setDaemon(true);
      threads[i].start();
    }
    /* wait for the threads to start */
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* tell only the third thread that it is able to continue */
    threads[2].setCanContinue(true);
    /* wake up all threads waiting on the 'lock', but only one of them is instructed to continue */
    synchronized (lock) {
      lock.notifyAll();
    }
    /* wait some time before exiting, thread two should be able to finish correctly, the others will be discarded with the end of the JVM */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      try {
        threads[i].join(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
  }

  /** synchronization object, i.e. a lock which makes sure that only one thread can get into "Critical Section" */
  private final Object lock = new Object();

  /** A simple thread to demonstrate the issue */
  private final class MyThread extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean canContinue;
    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " going to wait...");
      synchronized (lock) {
        while (!canContinue) {
          try {
            lock.wait(1000); /* one second */
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " woken up!");
    }
    public void setCanContinue(boolean canContinue) {
      this.canContinue = canContinue;
    }
  };
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
Thread-0 going to wait...
Thread-2 going to wait...
Thread-3 going to wait...
Thread-1 going to wait...
Thread-4 going to wait...
Thread-2 woken up!
Done!
```

So you can clearly see that only the third thread (indexed from zero) is woken up. You have to study the Java synchronization and multi-threading in more detail to understand every particular line of the code (for example, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)).

I would like to help you more, but I would have to write almost a book about Java threads and that is why I just pointed out to this [Java Tutorial on threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). You are right, this problematics is not easy at all, especially for beginners. So I advise you to read through the referenced tutorial and then you should be able to understand most of the code above. There is no easy way around or at least I do not know of any.

Comment: Hi Jiri, could you please explain the above program a little bi, so that it can help to understand more clear, and also it is possible to notify a single thread as I have written above that we want to notify only thread 3...!!

Comment: Hi Jiri can you please provide this example in simple terms as it is at very high level , for beginners like me it is very tough..!!thanks in advance..!!

Comment: It would be great if you can explain the same thing in similiar fashion but through simple terms ..!!that will be a great help and clear much more understanding ..!!thanks in advance..!!

Comment: See the last two paragraphs of my answer and also the JavaDoc in the SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) code.